# How to set the default class when two classes have the same name

Tags: c#

If I have two namespaces eg

```
using Code1.Dog;
using Code2.Cat;
```

and both namespaces have a class called "Legs", how I would i set the default one that is used, without writing a full name such as Code1.Dog.Legs?

In an ASP.NET controller I have a class called "User" but whenever I write it, it uses the default class in "System.Security.Principle". Would like to use my own class called "User" without using the full naming scheme eg "MyNamespace.User". How would I achieve this? There is no way to not include the original class "System.Security.Principle".

Comment: You could try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Answer (score 1):

When you have classes with the same simple names, you must refer to them by their fully qualified class names.

That's the way even you can understand your code better too.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but there must be a way to set a default, since just writing "User" is defaults to one namespace.